# Increment an integer in a form

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Form1 I have the following integer:

`public static int completed;`

I have multiple classes in my program; `Runner` is the superclass if you will then there is `Expert : Runner`, `Beginner : Runner` and `Disabled : Expert`

I basically have three `numericUpDown` boxes on my form for the user to input number to represent a time (hours, minutes and seconds). There is also a listbox called `lstRunners` that is populated using an array of objects, like so:

```
Runner[] runnerList;
runnerList = new Runner[10];
```

I have a button called `btnFinish`. What I am trying to do is add a method in the `Expert` class called `CountFinished24()` that I want to basically increment the `completed` integer by 1 if the selected Expert or Disabled runner has completed the run in 24:00:00 or less. This has to be recorded only for Expert and Disabled runners. I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a virtual OnFinished() method to Runner which gets called by btnFinish. Override this method for Expert and Disabled and increment the completed integer if they completed the race within 24h

Comment: @WeylandYutani Can you help with some sample code? I'm not 100% sure on what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating on Weyland's answer, you might have something like this in your Runner class:

```
 protected virtual int OnFinish(int h, int m, int s) 
 { 
      return 0;
 }
```

Then in ExpertRunner / DisabledRunner, you override OnFinish by simply adding the ovverride key word:

```
 protected override int OnFinish(int h, int m, int s)
 { 
      //IF the total time is less than 24:00:00
           return 1;
      else
           return 0;
 }
```

Then over on your form...

```
 private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      completed += myExpertRunner.OnFinish(numericHour, numericMinute, numericSecond);
 }
```

You might want to use some sort of custom object (or DateTime) to store H:M:S in a more easily consumable fashion. But anyways...

In essence, `override` lets you use a method that takes the same arguments and uses the same name but behaves differently.

A super common example is the `ToString()` method that belongs to all objects. When you call this method, it might simply return the object type as a string. Other objects override this ToString() method and return something different. For example, the StringBuilder class' ToString method returns a string with each "element" in it.

Read up on the [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword on MSDN. It also has examples. In their first example they use an abstract class, but in the second example they do something more similar to what I've written here.

Comment: Is there any way I can test to see if this is working i.e. output it to a string?

Comment: @user2929108 Certainly. All you'd need to do would be something like this inside your button click:

`MessageBox.Show(myExpertRunner.OnFinish().ToString());`

Here the ToString method simply converts the number to a string with that number in it :)

Comment: Where is the `myExpertRunner` and `count` from? These don't exist in my application.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot what you called it. `counter` is your `completed` integer. And as far `myExpertRunner` is concerned, that's just an instance of your `Expert` object. Since the method belongs to that class, and is **not** declared static, it must be called on an instance of that object.

Comment: Oh so I need to create a new instance of the object? I haven't done that.

Comment: @user2929108 Might help if you edit your original question and post the code for your main application so we can see better what you're doing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40667/discussion-between-user2929108-and-sab669)